# How to deploy asp.NET web site and database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, deployment, web-deployment

[My solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg1K8.jpg)

Actually, i deployed one of hosting domain's but getting [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied] error.

Should i seperate database and web project ?

Here is the website
http://ogunadsay-001-site1.btempurl.com/

Support service just send me this:

You can call the .exe file through code,but we do not support it runs directly on the server,please debug it at your local and republish your site.

What does it mean?

**EDIT**:
I solve the problem with finding csc.exe file in smarterasp.net's file manager and changing it's permission to read/write.

Comment: Are you on SmarterASP?

Comment: And are you trying to publish via deploy?

Comment: Yes i'm deploying my project to SmarterASP's free domain

Comment: Stand by for an answer.  I'll walk you through the process.

Comment: I would appreciate sir thank you

Answer (score 3):

These instructions will apply specifically to the user's host: SmarterASP, although the instructions should be pretty universal.

First, from your Hosting Control Panel, select the site you want to deploy to and make sure VS Deploy is set to on:

[image: VS Deploy]

I will note here the information that is provided under VS Web Deploy will go here (under Publish settings):

[image]

From the left control panel (SmarterASP), go to your Database Manager, select MSSQL Manager, and select +Add Database, (MSSQL 2012 or 2014 will be fine), name the database and create a password.

From visual studio, from the Publish menu (I'm assuming you at least made it this far), click the Settings Tab:

[image: Database Settings]

This is where you connect the Database Contexts from your project to a database.  Click the "More settings" (The command buttons with elipses), and copy the connection information from your Database Manager (SmarterASP) into the fields.

Test your DB connections, and if you succeeded you're ready to go.

And to answer your question: the database is in fact separated from the project.  Visual Studio runs a Local SQL server strictly for running locally, but when deploying the Database will be on an SQL Server.

Hope this helps.